# How to call a FastAPI route from NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, express, post, routes, fastapi

this is my FasiAPI route :

```
@app.post("/files/")
async def create_file(file: UploadFile = Form(...)):
    #some ml code
    return {'detected_face': base64_return, 'feature_vector': str(embedded)}
```

My webapp backend is running on NodeJs + ExpressJS. I have the file store in **'./uploads/filename.jpeg'**

FastAPI is running on : **localhost:8000**

Web backend server running on : **localhost:3000**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can send request directly through url: localhost:8000/ by using request module.

```
request('http://localhost:8000/files/<parameter>', function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body)
    }
})
```